# Cannot block some websites in macOS Safari

Tags: safari, hosts

I cannot block some websites in Safari using the etc/hosts trick.  Some websites are blocked, but not all.  For example `lichess.org` and `youtube.com` aren't getting blocked in Safari (but they are getting blocked in Chrome).

My etc/hosts file has the following lines...

```
0.0.0.0 www.youtube.com
0.0.0.0 youtube.com
```

and I entered this in terminal to flush the caches

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

And I cleared the safari cache and history.

And I rebooted.

Again, this blocks youtube in Chrome but not Safari.  Any ideas?